# How to retrieve a list of records and the count of each one's children with condition in Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There are two models with our familiar one-to-many relationship:

```
class Custom
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :custom
end
```

I want to do the following work:

get all the custom information whose age is over 18, and how many big orders(pay for 1,000 dollars) they have?

**UPDATE:**

for the models:

```
rails g model custom name:string age:integer
rails g model orders amount:decimal custom_id:integer
```

I hope one left join sql statement will do all my job, and don't construct unnecessary objects like this:

```
Custom.where('age > ?', '18').includes(:orders).where('orders.amount > ?', '1000')
```

It will construct a lot of order objects which I don't need, and it will calculate the count by `Array#count` function which will waste time.

**UPDATE 2:**
My own solution is wrong, it will remove customs who doesn't have big orders from the result.

Comment: What do your migrations look like so we can mimic the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Finding adult customers with big orders

This solution uses a single query, with the nested orders relation transformed into a sub-query.

```
big_customers = Custom.where("age > ?", "18").where(
  id: Order.where("amount > ?", "1000").select(:custom_id)
)
```

#### Grab all adults and their # of big orders (MySQL)

This can still be done in a single query. The count is grabbed via a join on `orders` and sticking the count of orders into a column in the result called `big_orders_count`, which `ActiveRecord` turns into a method. It involves a lot more "raw" SQL. I don't know any way to avoid this with `ActiveRecord` except with the great [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem.

```
adults = Custom.where("age > ?", "18").select([
  Custom.arel_table["*"],
  "count(orders.id) as big_orders_count"
]).joins(%{LEFT JOIN orders
           ON orders.custom_id = customs.id
           AND orders.amount > 1000})

# see count:
adults.first.big_orders_count
```

You might want to consider caching counters like this. This join will be expensive on the database, so if you had a dedicated `customs.big_order_count` column that was either refreshed regularly or updated by an observer that watches for big `Order` records.

#### Grab all adults and their # of big orders (PostgreSQL)

Solution 2 is mysql only. To get this to work in postgresql I created a third solution that uses a sub-query. Still one call to the DB :-)

```
adults = Custom.where("age > ?", "18").select([
  %{"customs".*},
  %{(
      SELECT count(*)
      FROM orders
      WHERE orders.custom_id = customs.id
      AND orders.amount > 1000
    ) AS big_orders_count}
])

# see count:
adults.first.big_orders_count
```

I have tested this against postgresql with real data. There may be a way to use more ActiveRecord and less SQL, but this works.

Comment: I want to get 1)all the adult customs not only rich customs 2) the each one's big order count, zero if none. It will not work for that either, right?

Comment: @SefierTang Answer updated. Should be what you actually wanted, still in a single query.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain where does `amount >= 1000`go? And I'm afraid left join with condition will remove custom without big orders, please think of that too.

Comment: Thanks, but I think `right join` is worse than `left join`, it will not only remove customs without big orders, but also will remove customs without any order, am I right?

Comment: I think right join will only reserve all the records from the right table, which is `orders`, so it will remove customs without orders.

Comment: @SefierTang `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins in mysql are [actually the same](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). They both differ from `INNER` joins in that they do **not** exclude records when a matching record is not found in the join table. I have tried the above code on actual data and it works as expected, finding `Custom` records have have no orders as well as ones that do. I changed my answer to use `LEFT JOIN` since that is more portable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using postgres, so I could only use `left join`, maybe I should point it out when asking the question, and this solution works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's no `group by`, then count(*) comes from where?

Comment: @SefierTang My attempt #2 is mysql only. I figured out how to do it in postgresql with a sub-query. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: It really works on `pg`, thanks! And may I ask this subquery will be executed before or after custom filter? The former one seems cost a lot.

Comment: The clauses in the outer query (the `customs` table) will take precedence over the sub-query. There is no before/after really since `pg`s query planner should actually transform this into an outer join type query internally and execute as a single query to two tables, instead of executing the sub-query for every `Custom` record. What order it scans records in will be up to what it decides is the best approach based on indexes. The resulting dataset will be unaffected by what the query planner decides.

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

```
@custom_over_18 = Custom.where("age > ?", "18").orders.where("amount > ?", "1000").count
```

Comment: It will work, but as my update, is there any better way?

Comment: I am afraid this sentence will even raise an error, as there's no method `orders` on `ActiveRecord::Relation`.